# More than one Field in algorithms in the Modeler Processing

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

Is it a way to enter more than one field in an algorithm in the Processing Modeler like in the toolbox?

An example with the algorithm "dissolve" in the toolbox:
[image]

The same algorithme in the modeler:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - separate them with `;` characters. Eg `NOM_RESEAU;ANNEE`

Comment: Many thanks. I think i have tried all other possibilities

Comment: For future reference: Whitespace characters are *not* allowed between names.